# Android/Eclipse: Zone of transparency in a png image

Tags: android, eclipse, image, png

I have a png image with a zone of transparency in it. I would like to add a Surface View in this zone of transparency. Could you please give me some tips? I've been looking on this site and on google for hours and did not find something I could use.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a FrameLayout and put your png on top of the SurfaceView as an overlay.

```
<FrameLayout>
 <SurfaceView>
 <ImageView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
Just a question: will the photo I save have the dimensions of the zone of transparency (it would be great) or the dimensions of all the screen?